# Notepad++ find under a condition?

Tags: regex, notepad++

This is my sentence

```
「システム、スキャンモード。特定しました。
```

This sentence has a CRLF at the end. I wish to match the `。CRLF` at the end, but ONLY if the string starts with `「`.
I thought it would not be too hard to do this but I couldn't do it.
I tried multiple variations of

```
^(?=「).*。\R
```

This will go through the condition, but matches the whole line instead of just `。CRLF`
I am a regex newbie, so I think this is probably not hard at all. I am just not very knowledgeable about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can match `「` at the beginning of a line first and then use `\K` to discard the current matched text from the final match:

```
^「.*\K。\R
```

Comment: Thank you. Your exact line didn't work for me, but I did this `^(?=「).*\K。\R` and that worked.